# Transitive closure of $H=\{(a,b) \in \mathbb{R}^2: |a-b| \leq 0.1\}$

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

$$H = \{(a, b)  \in \mathbb{R}^2: |a − b| \leq 0.1\}$$

In class today we went over this problem as an example to show transitive closure.  I know that the transitive closure of $H$ is "All real numbers", but I am not sure why.  Would someone here be able to explain it to me?

Comment: The transitive closure of a relation should be another relation. Thus "all real numbers" actually means "all pairs of real numbers", i.e. the relation $R = \{(a,b) \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}\}$.

Comment: Or equivalently, for the transitive closure, each euivalence class is the set of all real numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $|a-b| < n \cdot 0.1$, then $(a,b)$ lies in $H^{\circ n}$ and hence in the transitive closure. Since $\{n \cdot 0.1 : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is unbounded, we are done.